# How to share binaries resulting from compilation (when using git or other VCS)?

Tags: git, version-control, binaries

How can I share binary files (resulting from compilation) with git (or other VCS)?

I mean *share* and not *track*; I don't need the whole history of the file, I just need a **good practice** to upload/download my latest software binaries (to share it as easily as I share my code with git). I know this is not what a version control system is suppose to do.

I read an [article about how to store large binary files with git](http://blog.deveo.com/storing-large-binary-files-in-git-repositories/) but as far as I understood, this is more about versioning than sharing.

Note: this question has probably been asked already, but I can't find where.

Comment: If you put them into a VCS, all versions will be tracked. Put them somewhere else (such as a Maven repository or a Docker repository or an FTP server).

Comment: Git hosts -- GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket, etc. -- usually provide hosting for built files alongside, but separate from, the Git repository.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge like [releases](https://help.github.com/articles/distributing-large-binaries/) on Github for example? I didn't know about that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Git hosts -- GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket, etc. -- usually provide hosting for built files alongside, but separate from, the Git repository.

For example, GitHub provides [releases](https://help.github.com/articles/distributing-large-binaries/). [Those steps](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/) enable to upload a compiled release.

GitLab also supports [releases](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/api/tags.md#create-a-new-release).

BitBucket provides [downloads](https://bitbucket.org/arthursw/probuilder/downloads), as discussed [here](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/11404/bitbucket-equivalent-of-github-releases-bb).

Assembla also provides file [updload/download](https://helpdesk.assembla.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1677000-files-tool-user-guide).